# Form builder customization

Tags: jquery

I am developing an application form builder.
I am using the following 
http://minikomi.github.io/Bootstrap-Form-Builder/

I downloaded it for github, 
I am able to edit the form and all,
but I don't know how it is getting saved.
Can anyone tell me how it works.

Answer (score 0):

On the Rendered.html tab you can get the html code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the textbox id render. The value will be in the textbox with id render

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#getmyCode").click(function () {
            alert($("#render").val());
        });
    });
</script>
```